# rails3 + liquid parse question

Tags: parsing, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

I have a question in using luquid. My question is like this,

I have a model called 'Page' (with is an ActiveRecord::Base 
inherited) ,  and it has a column called  'content' which will store 
the html page content.

I have a code to display it as follows

```
<%@template = Liquid::Template.parse(page_content) %> 
<%=  @template.render('page_content' => yield)  %>
```

where 'page_content' has implemented in application helper as follows

```
def current_site_layout 
    Page.find(1). content 
end
```

but my problem is if I have content as follows

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

It will display in the page as

`<h1>This is a test</h1>` (with `<h1></ h1>` tags)

where as I want it to print like

## This is a test

(formatting 
applied as h1)

what am I missing here , and I think I will have to use liquid_methods 
or something like that. But since I'm new to liquid I'm not sure which 
method to use.. can someone help me

I'm on rails3 and using gem 'liquid 2.2.2', from 'github.com/GnomesLab/ 
liquid.git'

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 3, strings are escaped by default. To display unescaped strings, you need to call `raw` method explicitly.

```
<%@template = Liquid::Template.parse(page_content) %> 
<%=  raw @template.render('page_content' => yield)  %>
```